# Error: HTML / PHP / JQuery No puedo limpiar los imput cuando cambio un select

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, textfield

Necesito que cuando cambie cambie una opción del select se borre un campo completado:

Cuando se selecciona elemento_tipo, habilita cargar el input elemento_valor, el problema está en que cuando cambio de opción en elemento_tipo nuevamente, el campo elemento_valor mantiene el valor que se le ingresó.

Desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier sugerencia.

Pego parte del código.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_tipo']['label']; ?>
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_tipo']['form']; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_valor']['label']; ?>
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_valor']['form']; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_secundario']['label']; ?>
        <?php echo $fields['elemento_secundario']['form']; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#servicio_table').DataTable({
            language: {
                url: 'plugins/datatables/spanish.json'
            },
            dom: 't',
            paging: false,
            autoWidth: false,
            searching: false,
            ordering: false,
            scrollY: '400px',
        });

        $('#elemento_valor, #elemento_secundario').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#elemento_tipo').change(function() {
            $('#elemento_valor, #elemento_secundario').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#elemento_secundario')[0].selectize.disable();
            opcion = $(this).val();
            if (jQuery.inArray(opcion, ['3', '4']) != -1) {
                $('#elemento_valor').attr('disabled', false);
            }
            if (opcion === '5') {
                $('#elemento_secundario')[0].selectize.enable();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Bienvenido Pablo. Estás en SO en Español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta para evitar que sea cerrada.

Comment: Perdón, creí que era todo lo mismo, ahora la traduzco, cómo hago para publicarla en este sitio y en el que no es sólo español?

Comment: Se agradece el uso del punto y aparte. Has escrito un párrafo enorme con explicaciones confusas, el problema en concreto no logra entenderse. ¿Cuál es el problema?, por favor explícalo brevemente sin dar tantas vueltas. *El problema es este, con este elemento*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para eliminar los datos de un campo solo usa

```
$('select_a_manipular').val('')
```

Esto elimina lo que haya insertado el usuario dentro de un input, es lo que entiendo que quieres hacer aquí